# My server is removing obfuscated PHP code

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, obfuscation, malware

I know that there is a big controversy between obfuscating the code to protect it and not doing it because people consider it useless. In this case I chose to obfuscate my code just to make it more difficult to decode, just as adding a lock to a window, windows can always be broken, but we still chose to lock them.

That being said, I am running an obfuscated code on my server but every time I upload it, it works for a few hours and then it gets removed, not the file but the obfuscated code within the file gets removed.

This looks like some kind of anti-viurs, anti-malware running on the server but I have no idea where to start looking.

We have a LAMP architecture with Centos, cpanel / WHM, dedicated server and root access.
My first guess is cpanel , there must be a script running that can be managed from WHM.

Thanks

Comment: ClamAV possibly `cleaning` infected file?    
https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Configure+ClamAV+Scanner

Possibly you are using eval(...  in a way that looks like an infection.

Comment: I believe the same thing as you, but ClamAV is not installed, any other setting I can look into

Comment: I would assume something AV related would be server wide, likely only accessable from the WHM panel. Sorry, can't help more than that.

Comment: I think Suhosin module can disable eval, but I am not sure about removing files. Sound more like something an ISP will do, but they should send you a notice about it.